# Is it possible to select from the result of a subquery in a join

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a large subquery and I would like to join on that subquery while using the result of the subquery in the join.

For example, I have a table called `patient` and one called `appointment`, and I would like to get the number of appointments per patient with given criteria.

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      patient.name,
      patient.id,
      appointment.date
    FROM
      patient
      LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.patient_id = patient.id
    WHERE
      /* a **lot** of filters, additional joins, etc*/
  ) t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) number_of_appointments,
      patient.id
    FROM
      patient
      LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.patient_id = patient.id
    GROUP BY
      patient.id
  ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

The problem is that this returns the number of appointments for each patient independent from the subquery above it. I tried writing the join as this:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) number_of_appointments,
      patient.id
    FROM
      t1
    GROUP BY
      patient.id
  )
```

But obviously I'm getting an error saying that table t1 doesn't exist. Is there any way for me to do this cleanly without having to repeat all of the filters from t1 in t2?

Thanks!

Comment: Considering abstracting some of that large subquery into a stored procedure of some sort, so you can save on the typing in other queries

Answer (score 1):

Why not use window functions?

```
SELECT p.name, p.id, a.date,
       COUNT(a.patient_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) as num_appointments
FROM patient p LEFT JOIN
     appointment a
     ON a.patient_id = p.id
WHERE . . .
```

This provides the count based on the `WHERE` filtering.  If you wanted a count of *all* appointments, then do the calculation before applying the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT p.name, p.id, a.date,
       COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) as num_total_appointments,
       COUNT(a.patient_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) as num_matching appointments
FROM patient p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.patient_id) as cnt
      FROM appointment a
     ) a
     ON a.patient_id = p.id
WHERE . . .
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly; if I wanted to do a `GROUP_CONCAT()` as well, do you know the best way I could do that? Unfortunately it doesn't seem like `GROUP_CONCAT()` is supported with window functions..Thanks :)

Comment: @DM5963 . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data and desired results.  This appears to answer the question that you have asked.